# Regex to extract substrings

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

The following file is given:

```
  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  @but.label: '{i18n>Attr4.Name}'
  '' as Name: String(80),

  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  @but.label: '{i18n>Asddf.Time}'
  Time,

  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  @but.label: '{i18n>asdfdsf.Attr}'
  Prop: String(80),

  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  Another: String(80),

  @but.label: '{i18n>ddfdf.asdfasdf}'
  AS: Association to Back not null;

  @but.label: '{i18n>desdfadf.adsfdf}'
  description: localized String;
```

I would like to match the following via capturing groups:

- Attr4.Name & Name
- Asddf.Time & Time
- asdfdsf.Attr & Prop
- ddfdf.asdfasdf & AS
- desdfadf.adsfdf & description

So far I have:
`@but\.label:\s*'\{i18n>([\w.]+)\}'[\s\S]*?\s([^@\s]\w+)`

I am stuck with the  `'' as` part, which I want to exclude.

Comment: Can you also include your JS code?

Comment: Start the match with an uppercase A-Z `@but\.label:\s*'\{i18n>([\w.]+)\}'[\s\S]*?\s([A-Z]\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/E1FZdq/1

Comment: What kind of syntax is this? Is it some kind of configuration file?

Comment: CDS - Core Data Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of matching `\s([^@\s]\w+)` where the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) which will match any char except an @ or whitespace char, you could start the match with A-Z like `\s([A-Z]\w+)` or add a-z to the negated character class `\s([^a-z@\s]\w+)`

```
@but\.label:\s*'\{i18n>([\w.]+)\}'[\s\S]*?\s([A-Z]\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7Eb68/1)

---

Or use a capturing group listing all the allowed values `\s(Name|Time|Prop)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mWjGcG/1)

```js
    const str = `@ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  @but.label: '{i18n>Attr4.Name}'
  '' as Name: String(80),

  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  @but.label: '{i18n>Asddf.Time}'
  Time,

  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  @but.label: '{i18n>asdfdsf.Attr}'
  Prop: String(80),

  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @but.creatable: false
  @but.updatable: false
  Another: String(80),`;
    let m;
    const regex = /@but\.label:\s*'{i18n>([\w.]+)\}'.*\r?\n.*?\s([A-Z]\w+)/g;
    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }
        console.log(m[1]);
        console.log(m[2]);
        console.log("\n");
    }
```

**Edit**

If the second capturing group can not start with as you can use the case insensitive flag `/i` and use a negative lookahead:

```
@but\.label:\s*'\{i18n>([\w.]+)\}'[\s\S]*?\s(?!AS)([A-Za-z]\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BpBU1j/1)

Comment: Just saw that actually more scenarios are possible, I added my original question. Otherwise the answer of The fourth bird would have been correct. I now have the following solution which seems to work: `@but\.label:\s*'\{i18n>([\w.]+)\}'[\s\S]*?\s((?!AS\s|as\s|aS\s|As\s)[A-Z|a-z]\w+)`. Do you think I am godd to go with that? Can it be simplified?

Comment: @psdevHD you could use the case insensitive flag `/i` and then shorten the pattern to `@but\.label:\s*'\{i18n>([\w.]+)\}'[\s\S]*?\s((?!AS)[A-Za-z]\w+)` See https://regex101.com/r/97229c/1